# ADB driver for Samsung does not respond in remote debugging

Tags: adb, samsung, usb-debugging

To summarise the situation, I tried all the steps and quirks to make remote debugging work for a Samsung Galaxy S4, and Galaxy A3, the chrome://inspect page never picks up anything, I tried with different data cables and different PCs, finally, when I tried with a Huawei mobile, it immediately picked up.

The ADB device in **Device Manager** does not seem to have any issues, it shows under group: **Samsung Android Phone**

Huawei on the other hand installed **Universal Serial Bus devices > ADB interface**, which is never active while connecting the Samsung.

What is so different about Samsung? What else does it need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work. Here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

I installed the application and went through the process, then in command prompt, changed to C:\adb, and tried different adb commands, I do not quite know the thing that triggered the change, the ones I tried:

```
>adb -d
>adb kill_server
>adb usb
```

That made it work!